# Django: Get first Choice Value from tuple

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

## Models.py

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
        ('M', 'Male'),
        ('F', 'Female'),
    )
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=200, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
    to_be_listed = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

## views.py

```
def index(request,get_gender):
    all_details = {
        'list': Person.objects.filter(gender=get_gender).order_by('-id'),
    }

    return render(request,'index/person.html',context=all_details)
```

On index, I'm getting M or F as a get_gender parameter but when I get it from a model I'm getting second value from the tuple (male or female) but I need to get first value(m or f).

How to get m or f from the tuple?

Comment: Why do you not simply define your `CATEGORY_CHOICES` as `(
        ('M', 'M'),
        ('F', 'F'),
    )` ?

Comment: `get_gender` you are passing as a parameter to the index() method.

Answer (score 4):

In your **template** html:

> **From your person object:**

To get **`'M'` or `'F'`:**

```
{{person.gender}}
```

and to get **`'Male'` or `'Female'`:**

```
{{person.get_gender_display}}
```